# Running an ONNX model from file contents

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, onnx, onnxruntime

I'm trying to serve an ONNX model to the user and the model file is the largest in my React app. I'd like to decrease the size of this file by zipping it. However, the only command I'm aware of to initialize the ONNX runtime session is `sess = await onnx.InferenceSession.create(filename)`

Is there a good way around this? Some ideas - please tell me if any are feasible:

- use a different function in ONNX, allowing me to serve the file as a zip and unzip client-side in js, then read and pass the contents to ONNX
- transmit all files zipped and unzip them transparently
- unzip the file into memory and pass some sort of memory URI to ONNX

Which is the preferred option, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Hi, me with my two cents again:-) In addition to paths to ONNX models, the `ort.InferenceSession` constructor also supports `bytes` inputs. I.e. if you unzip the file into memory, you should be able to load the model by just passing the memory buffer to `InferenceSession` as-is. However, generally, zipping a ML model **should not** affect it's size too much. If your `.onnx` file gets considerably smaller after compression, it *probably* means your model is overparametrized and you could do with a smaller architecture.

Comment: Thank you! Interesting - I think my model does have duplication, specifically because I have a slightly nonstandard architecture where a subcomponent is trained separately and then applied explicitly to x1...x8 and then again to x9...x16. And then I have several outputs that are somewhat duplicative, but which I want to run in WASM rather than in JS. So you may not be wrong but there aren't terrible reasons for it! I discovered scs4onnx, which is very helpful. I'll try unzipping into memory!